# Autolayout - Compressing UINavigationController at the same time as pushing a new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, autolayout

I am working on an iOS app. The root view controller contains a UINavigationController which wraps up the main contents of the app, and a footerViewController (audio player) that will compress the main content when it animates up into view.

I’m using auto layout to show and hide this footer like so:

```
_footerVisibleConstraints = [… @“V:|[navControllerView][footerView(==90)]|" …];
_footerHiddenConstraints = [… @“V:|[navControllerView][footerView(==0)]|" …];
```

Generally this works well. But I’m struggling with one issue. I have a situation where I need to push a new view on the UINavigationController stack and animate my footer into view the same time:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
  [[self view] removeConstraints:_footerHiddenConstraints];
  [[self view] addConstraints:_footVisibleConstraints];
  [[self view] layoutIfNeeded];
}];

[navigationController pushViewController:newViewController animated:YES];
```

The problem in this situation is that newViewController is animating in snapped to it's final (compressed) state, and not beginning from the full starting height of the view. So there is a gap at the bottom while the footer animates in.

I’ve slowed down the animation and posted a video [here](http://vimeo.com/100362170) to demonstrate what I am describing.

Also, notice how when I pop back to the root view controller the content in the UINavigationController isn’t compressed either.

So, can someone explain to me what’s going on here? Is there a way to accomplish what I am after?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable to the .h of your VC to stipulate whether the footer needs to open or not. Then add the footer animation to the didAppear method with a check on the variable. This will result in performing the actions in the order you want them to happen.

If you want both animations to happen at the same time you will need to subclass a segue and add a custom animation.

Comment: Yes, if I use the viewDidAppear method on the newViewController to trigger the footer animating it works fine. But what I am really after is having the effect work with viewWillAppear so it feels like one smooth animation.

Comment: Like I added to my answer you have to write your own segue animation. You will basically have to overwrite `- (void)perform`

Comment: Since the push/pop animations are all effecting the subviews UINavigationController view. Shouldn’t those subviews respond properly to the change in size of their superview? Are they not animated with auto layout constraints? For example if my phone is landscape/portrait, all of the seque animations respond properly. Really all I am doing is changing the size of the Superview for all of those objects. Even if I were to override perform, I’m can’t figure what I’d implement differently as that seque would not really be responsible for controlling the animation of the superview.